# ArrayList to Map in Java

Tags: java, android, list, map

Есть неупорядоченный список обьектов типа Product.

```
class Product
{
    int realization_date;
    String name;
}
```

Мне нужно его преобразовать в Map таким образом чтобы в качестве ключа был **realization_date** а в качестве значения - `List<String>`.

Поясняю. В этом списке могут быть несколько продуктов с разными названиями но реализоваными в в одну дату, т.е. на выходе у меня должно быть такой результат :

Map `<Integer,List<String>>` Чтобы по дате я мог получить список продуктов реализованных в данный день.

#### Udpate

Варианты с тривиальным заполнением и последующим map.get(key) не предлагать. На вход подается ключ - обьект класса Integer. HashMap ищет в себе такой же ключ по хешу. Не находит, хотя обьект идентичен, т.к. хеш обьекта не находится среди списка ключей в мапе.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: О, теперь у вопроса появился смысл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкратце: У вас мутируют объекты, находящиеся в `HashMap`. Так делать запрещено. Не делайте этого, и всё будет работать правильно и очевидным образом.

Теперь детали. `HashMap` поддерживает независимые подсписки (buckets) элементов, индексированные значением хэшкода, который объект имел на момент добавления. При поиске Hashmap вычисляет хэшкод объекта, находит соответствующий подсписок, и ограничивает поиск этим подсписком. `HashMap` **не рассматривает** самой возможности, что элемент находится в другом подсписке.

Это означает, что категорически запрещено всё, что может приводить к изменению хэшкода объекта, пока он находится в `HashMap`. В документации на `Map` есть даже более строгое требование, запрещающее даже модификацию объекта, влияющую на `equals` (вы же помните, что `equals` строго сильнее `hashCode`: `a.equals(b)` => `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`):

> Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.

Чините.

Comment: А если equals и hashcode уже переопределены?

`hash = super.hashCode();
hash = hash * 3;`

Comment: Важно лишь то, чтобы `hashCode` одного и того же объекта **не менялся** в то время, пока этот объект находится внутри `HashMap`. 

Если ваш `hashCode()` рассчитывается на основании `super.hashCode()`, выясните, меняется ли `super.hashCode()` при изменении объекта.

Лучше всего не пытаться обмануть систему и просто не менять объект.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле такую задачу среднестатистический программист решает 2-3 раза в неделю.. Странно не уметь это делать с закрытыми глазами, ещё более странно, что никто не написал уже эти несколько строчек кода...

```
Set<Product> products ...
Map<Integer,List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
for(Product prod : product) {
  if(!result.containsKey(prod.realization_date))
      result.put(prod.realization_date, new ArrayList<String>());        
  result.get(prod.realization_date).add(prod.name);
}
return result;
```

Comment: @AndrewFrolov: Никто не написал эти несколько строчек кода потому, что они тривиальны, и среднестатистическому участнику сайта (например, мне) не интересно разжёвывать то, что ТС мог бы выяснить, не поленившись заглянуть на 5 минут в [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Спасибо вам от имени ТС за неравнодушие. Но подсказывать такие простые вещи на мой взгляд неправильно. Умение читать документацию для программиста — это как знать названия фигур для шахматиста, основа основ.

Comment: @VladD совершенно с вами согласен!

Comment: Какие все умные когда хэш объекта остается неизменным.

Comment: полностью согласен с первым комментарием, типичный пример капитализма: в погоне за наживой забыли о главном

Comment: @Sergey Shustikov: пока объект лежит в Set/Map, он **не имеет права изменяться**. Из [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html): 

> Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is **not specified** if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.

В переводе на нормальный язык это означает: если объекты, находящиеся во множестве, мутируют (меняются) — ждите неприятностей. (Прежде всего от вашего архитектора.)